# Organizing large scale javascript web app

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, requirejs

I'm working on a big javascript web app. (which is mostly a web game)

Currently the code is written using only jQuery and the Module pattern.

The app is growing big and it gets harder and harder to maintain due to 2 reasons:

1. Separating the code into different files forces me to add a ton of script tags on each html page of the app. I'm looking into requireJS to solve that, is there another recommended solution?
2. Intellisense is having a hard time connecting different files and most of the time doesn't recognize objects that are defined in other files. How can it be fixed? I'm using VS Code.

Thank you!

Comment: This is largely opinion-based, but webpack is the defacto standard for bundling clientside assets (including js)

Comment: I was going to suggest requireJS.  Seems like it's what you're looking for.